# How to assign different task for each button clicked in Android?

Tags: android, string, button, http-post

Let's say I want to click a button and send a namevaluestring from phone to  the server.
And when I click another button, it sends another array of strings from application to server. Is there a way?

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button cnfrm;
private Button absnt;
private Button ntfy;
private ProgressBar pb;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
cnfrm =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
absnt =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
ntfy =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
cnfrm.setOnClickListener(this);
absnt.setOnClickListener(this);
ntfy.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(toString());  
        break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(toString());  
        break;
    case R.id.button3 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(toString());  
    break;

    }

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    postData(params[0]);
return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);

}

public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.20.154.8:8080/Server/ChangeStatus");

try {
    // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RestaurantID","0002"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkin",Integer.toString(1)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("absent",Integer.toString(0)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notify",Integer.toString(0)));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } }}}


    /*break;
case R.id.button2 :
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RestaurantID","0002"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkin",Integer.toString(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("absent",Integer.toString(1)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notify",Integer.toString(0)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        break;
case R.id.button3 :
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RestaurantID","0002"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkin",Integer.toString(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("absent",Integer.toString(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notify",Integer.toString(1)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        break;
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Post what you tried?

Comment: create common asyncClass and pass diff values when button clicked..

Comment: @Manish added my code!

Comment: @Prag'sシ added Asynctask but i couldn't get the app to run the different combination of strings...

Comment: @Erika wait for the answer dear...

Comment: @Prag'sシ Thank you for being so helpful! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onClick events you can implements like this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.button1 :
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RestaurantID","0002"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
    new MyAsyncTask(nameValuePairs).execute(toString());  
    break;
case R.id.button2 :
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RestaurantID","1111"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","2222222"));
    new MyAsyncTask(nameValuePairs).execute(toString()); 
    break;
case R.id.button3 :
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ABC","1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PQR","2"));
    new MyAsyncTask(nameValuePairs).execute(toString());   
break;

}

}
```

Here is your AsyncTask implementation as

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
public MyAsyncTask(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    this.nameValuePairs=nameValuePairs;
}

 @Override
 protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
postData()
return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent",  
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
pb.setProgress(progress[0]);

}

 public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new      
 HttpPost("http://172.20.154.8:8080/Server/ChangeStatus");

 try {
// Add your data
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} }}}
```

I hope with this you will get the basic idea for you requirements. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this...

**Define public variable for `NameValuePair`..**

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
```

**Create Parameter Constructor in your class..**

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    List<NameValuePair> parameters = null;

    // parameter constructor..
    public MyAsyncTask (List<NameValuePair> params) {
        parameters = params;
    }



    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR_WEB_ADDRESS);

    try {
        // this will pass different data everytime (which you have passed in costrocter.
        // make sure that you don't pass null value..
           if(parameters != null){
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
            Log.v("MyAsyncTask", "Parameters :" + parameters); 
           }

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    // DO YOUR CODING..

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    return null;
    }
}
```

**Now Call Your `AsyncClass` with different parameters for every different button..**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", VALUE));
        new MyAsyncTask(params).execute();  
        break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", VALUE));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", VALUE));
        new MyAsyncTask(params).execute();  
        break;
    case R.id.button3 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", VALUE));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", VALUE));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", VALUE));
        new MyAsyncTask(params).execute();  
    break;

    }

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes your code has given me an idea how to approach this. Thank you!